# Angular - Uncaught TypeError: Buffer is not a constructor

Tags: angular, xlsx

In my Angular-12, I have this excel service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
const EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
const EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ExcelServicesService {
  constructor() { }
  public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
  }
  private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {type: EXCEL_TYPE});
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + '_export_' + new  Date().getTime() + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
  }
}
```

component:

```
import { ExcelServicesService } from 'src/app/services/excel-services.service';

constructor(
  private excelService:ExcelServicesService,
) {
}

CountrySampleJson = [
  {
    "Name": "Egypt",
    "Nationality": "Cairo",
  },
  {
    "Name": "Ghana",
    "Nationality": "Accra",
  }
];

 exportCountrySample(): void {
  this.excelService.exportAsExcelFile(this.CountrySampleJson, 'Countries');
}
```

HTML:

```
<h5> Download the sample format<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="downloadSample()" value="Download Excel Template"/></h5>
```

When I served the Angular, the page is blank and I got this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Buffer is not a constructor
  at Array.Buffer.allocUnsafe (cpexcel.js:1026)
  at cpexcel.js:1028
  at cpexcel.js:991
  at Object.64203 (cpexcel.js:994)
  at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
  at make_xlsx_lib (xlsx.js:12)
  at Object.84487 (xlsx.js:21716)
  at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
  at Module.57411 (beforelogin.service.ts:7)
  at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
```

How do I get this sorted out?

Thanks

Comment: install buffer npm module then import it in ts file - "import * as buffer from 'buffer';"
Use it like this - buffer.Buffer

Comment: @PiyushJain - Can you give example based on my code

Comment: can you provide stackblitz link ?

Comment: Can you specify which **xlsx** version is used?

Comment: @YongShun - "xlsx": "^0.17.0",

Comment: I created [Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zcdygs?file=src/app/excel-services.service.ts). However, I cannot reproduce your issue; able to download the Excel file but the file is faulty. Can you have a look at it and try to configure it to match your project environment to reproduce the error. Thank you.

Comment: @YongShun - The error still persist. If I remove the reference  import { ExcelServicesService } from './excel-services.service';   the error is gone.   What else do I do?

Comment: @user11352561, do you mean the error from my StackBlitz link? Can share your StackBlitz link so that I can debug it?

Comment: @YongShun - No. Not from StackBlitz link. But from my code when I copied the same thing in StackBlitz link